# Was Mad Max the first post-apocalyptic film where biker gangs are among the survivors?

Tags: history-of, post-apocalyptic, mad-max

I would say that it was in the second movie where it is really clear that the producers envisaged people who were already outlaws (or borderline) as becoming the de facto leaders of future society such as it is.

This makes a lot of sense and I can think of countless subsequent films where it is biker  gangs or perhaps neo-nazis who end up on top. In The Postman, I forget, I think they are not just military but have some nazi/white supremacist leanings.

The low-budget but decent film Stake Land has a very clearly Christian Nationalist/neo-nazi group who see the monsters (sort of vampire-zombies) as fulfilling Christian end-of-days prophecy and they therefore help spread the plague which is both scary and plausible.

I think McCarthy in The Road sees neo-nazis as being the people running things.

Was Mad Max the first? Biker gangs are fairly new -- any pre-1960 scifi probably would not have seen biker gangs as a significant social force, but maybe since The Wild Ones was 1950s.

My guess is that anything much earlier simply has military warlords -- this is a very old idea, probably dating back to Verne. In real life, there must be countless examples of war-time and post-war gangs of trained and armed military men with their leaders invariably having a title like The Captain or The General.

The choice of biker gangs in Mad Max is an interesting departure, since why would not Australia end up being run by their own military? Perhaps the writers saw society as having declined so much that any formal military structure was less viable than smaller groups of bikers. (Interestingly opposed to technical people who despite their brains are basically at the mercy of the more ruthless bikers.)

Comment: First film or other work? [Lucifer's Hammer](https://inverarity.livejournal.com/187416.html) (1977) had a biker gang, who kidnapped/enslaved some Girl Scouts and were in turn taken down by Boy Scouts.

Comment: @Laurel: I guess even a story is of interest but movies represent a different sort of commitment to the idea -- I am sure if there is one short story or book there are many. A short scifi story from the 1950s about biker gangs running things would be very unexpected while by 1977, bikers as a subculture were widely known. in the 1950s, the outlaw biker gangs had probably less than 1000 members in the world.

Comment: Some of Norman Spinrad's short stories were devoted to post-apocalyptic bikers, but I don't think any made it into film. Zelazny's *Damnation Alley* had bikers galore, but unfortunately the movie left them out (as far as I remember).